# Can't open non HTTPS websites on mobile network. (Android Lollipop on Nexus 5, Nexus 4)

Tags: nexus-4, browser, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, https

I recently updated my Nexus 5 to Lollipop. The problem is that when I am on a mobile network, I can ONLY open HTTPS websites. All the HTTP websites appear as a blank white page. When I am on WiFi, everything is fine. I am located in India, if that matters.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Edit: Same is happening on another phone, which is Nexus 4. I have tried different browsers, and the results are the same.

Edit2: I used remote debugging on Android with Chrome.

Here is the response to `http://stackoverflow.com`

```
Remote Address:198.252.206.140:80
Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:504 Gateway Time-out
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:prov=5a7a2230-005c-463e-afda-63c634dd4a73; __qca=P0-84958589475-140584875859968; _ga=GA1.2.749475574.1948596847
Host:stackoverflow.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Nexus 5 Build/LRX21O) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.59 Mobile Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 17 Dec 2014 03:42:50 GMT
Server:WebProxy/6.0
```

When I try to open `https://stackoverflow.com`, here is what I get:

```
Remote Address:198.252.206.140:443
Request URL:https://stackoverflow.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:prov=5a7a2230-005c-463e-afda-63c634dd4a73; __qca=P0-84958589475-140584875859968; _ga=GA1.2.749475574.1948596847
Host:stackoverflow.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Nexus 5 Build/LRX21O) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.59 Mobile Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Cache-Control:public, max-age=39
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:19401
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 17 Dec 2014 03:43:21 GMT
Expires:Wed, 17 Dec 2014 03:44:01 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 17 Dec 2014 03:43:01 GMT
Vary:*
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Obviously, the HTTP request is getting timed out. I am on the Vodafone India network. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the APN settings to "VodafoneMobileConnect" fixed the problem.